# Can you set the default value/instance of a class for use in the default operator

Tags: c#

The title mostly says it. Is it possible to define the result value of a `default(T)` call? I'm not sure whether this would actually be useful, but one of the use-cases that I can think of is the `.FirstOrDefault()` function for Linq and its extensions. Of course you can just make a new instance and have your construtor set the properties up for you, but in the case of classes, I think it would be interesting and potentially useful (granted, in very niche cases) where `default(T)` returned an instance rather than null.

I haven't yet found any indication that this is possible, so if it is not, is there anything like this with a similar effect apart from just null checking? ie. `foo.FirstOrDefault() ?? new T();`

Comment: You could use `foo.DefaultIfEmpty(value).First();` for value type enumerables, but outside of LINQ there's no way to "override" default.

Comment: `default(TClass)` (where `TClass : class`) is **always** `null`.

Comment: .NET6 added an overload for FirstOrDefault, where you can specify what the default value shall be if no entry was found: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-firstordefault-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to define the result value of a default(T) call?

No.

- `default(T) where T : struct` is *always* the value of `T` where its underlying memory is entirely zero-valued bytes.
- `default(T) where T : class` is *always* `null`.

For some specific examples, in the cases of integers, `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, nullable structs, generic `TEnum` and `notnull` constraints this still applies:

- `default(Int32)` is always `0`.
- `default(DateTime)` is always `DateTime.MinValue`.
- `default(TimeSpan)` is always `TimeSpan.Zero`.
- `default(TimeSpan?)` (a nullable struct) is always `(TimeSpan?)null`.
- `default(TEnum) where TEnum : struct, Enum` is always `(TEnum)0`.
- `default(T) where T : notnull` will give you a compiler warning or error.

> I'm not sure whether this would actually be useful

It would not be useful because it would break the semantics of the widely understood `default(T)` operator.

And it would be a bad idea for program performance: the `default(T)` operator is used to initialize locals and fields to known default/zero values and is always expected to be fast. If `default(T)` had to run a custom constructor then it would ruin things like a `default`-initialized array, e.g. `new CustomStruct[1000]`.

> but one of the use-cases that I can think of is the `.FirstOrDefault()` function for Linq and its extensions

If that is your conclusion it means you're using `.FirstOrDefault()` and/or nullable-reference-types incorrectly.

I do appreciate that Linq does require tedium when using `.FirstOrDefault()` with value-types - I wish Linq had a stock `T? FirstOrNull<T>() where T : struct` method instead. Though it's easy to implement that yourself.

> Of course you can just make a new instance and have your constructor set the properties up for you, but in the case of classes, I think it would be interesting and potentially useful (granted, in very niche cases) where `default(T)` returned an instance rather than `null`.

Just use `.DefaultIfEmpty()` like you're meant to.

> I haven't yet found any indication that this is possible

It is not possible. The C# language specification does not allow for overloading or altering the semantics of `default(T)`.

> so if it is not, is there anything like this with a similar effect apart from just `null` checking? ie. `foo.FirstOrDefault() ?? new T();`

I don't know. It depends on your application and what your end objective is, which you haven't told us.